# PDFView context menu event handler -- changing highlight color

Tags: swift, pdfview, pdf-annotations, apple-pdfkit

I have a [PDFView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/) in an app. It allows you to highlight certain text. When you click on a highlight, the built in menu appears:

[image]

In the Preview.app, when you click one of those colors (or the remove highlight) menu item, it does what you expect (changes colors; removes the highlight). In my PDFView, this context menu does pop up, but does not change colors or remove highlights. Add note and others (e.g., single page, zoom in, etc.) seem to work out of the box. How do I implement an event handler for these default contextual menu items?